# LiveWire methods not working on simple compnent

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

i created a new simple components for using into `liveWire` and i'm trying to use this component from a single route, in below simple implementation `increment` and `decrement` not working for me

route:

```php
Route::get('/login',LoginComponent::class);
```

`LoginComponent::class`:

```php
class LoginComponent extends Component
{
    public $count = 10;

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.auth.login')->layout('livewire.auth.app');
    }

    public function increment()
    {
        $this->count++;
    }

    public function decrement()
    {
        $this->count--;
    }
}
```

`app.blade.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    ...

    @livewireStyles
</head>

<body>
    <div class="page-content">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            @yield('content')
        </div>
    </div>

    @livewireScripts
</body>

</html>
```

and then `login.blade.php`:

```
<div>
    @section('content')
        <div class="page-content">
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="content d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                    <div style="text-align: center">
                        <button wire:click="increment"> + </button>

                        <button wire:click="decrement"> - </button>

                        <h1>{{ $count }}</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endsection
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use proper rendering methods.

```
return view('livewire.auth.login')
    ->extends('livewire.auth.app')
    ->section('content');
```

And remove `@section('content')` from the login.blade.php

Check the docs on [Rendering Components](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/rendering-components)

Comment: could you clarify what happened? i don't understand me in docs

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the older @yield/@section Laravel style as described in the Livewire documentation and had no problem.

Your app.blade.php seems ok.

But your LoginController render method have to use extends():

```
public function render()
{
    return view('livewire.auth.login')->extends('livewire.auth.app');
}
```

And you should remove @section from your login.blade.php component.